# Python regular expression for different words & number

Tags: python, regex

How can I match any of these words: `'true', 'yes', 'Yes', 'on', 'On', '1', 1, True` ?

I've tried with `'^[1][{t,T}rue]|[]{y,Y}es]|[{o,O}n]|['1']^$'` but I can't achieve it.

Comment: Does your own attempt use something else than the most common GREP notation?

Comment: Don't use a regular expression? `if x in ('true', 'yes', 'Yes', 'on', 'On', '1', 1, True):`. If it's Python 3, you can make it (possibly) slightly more efficient by changing the parens to braces, `if x in {'true', 'yes', 'Yes', 'on', 'On', '1', 1, True}:`, which in modern Python constructs a constant `frozenset` for lookup, changing linear search to `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: [Fancy regex here :)](https://regex101.com/r/qD2eS8/1). Or `r"'(?:true|yes|on|1)'|\b(?:true|yes|on|1)\b"`. But you do not have to use a regex here really.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I don't recognize *any* of OP's patterns as common GREP expressions. That makes it hard to suggest what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def is_yes(x):
    return str(x).lower() in ('1', 'true', 'yes', 'on')

for x in ['true', 'yes', 'Yes', 'on', 'On', '1', 1, True, False, None, 0, 'no', 'random']:
    print(is_yes(x))
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: Excellent.  I like the call to `str` prior to `lower`. OP, do note that this accepts `'yES'`, which is probably what you want, but is important to note if it's not.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter with so short a data structure, but I would make `('1', 'true', 'yes', 'on')` a `set` instead: `{'1', 'true', 'yes', 'on'}`.  (Matter of fact, I have a hazy memory of doing some timings on a StackOverflow question and finding that very short lists outperformed small sets for searches, but I could be wrong.  That conclusion was the opposite of conventional wisdom.  But the standard practice is if you're going to use a data structure primarily for membership testing then use one optimized for it which in this case is a set.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regexp :

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "'true', 'yes', 'Yes', 'on', 'On', '1', 1, True"
>>> re.findall("yes|Yes|true|True|on|On|1", string)
['true', 'yes', 'Yes', 'on', 'On', '1', '1', 'True']
```

Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be conflating two problems ... not everything in your list is a string, so you cannot check all of them against a regular expression.

But assuming you're converting all of those to strings:

```
tests = map(str, ['true', 'yes', 'Yes', 'on', 'On', '1', 1, True])
```

Then all you'll need as a regex is this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('True|Yes|On|1', re.I)
```

Which will catch all of them:

```
print all(map(regex.match, tests))
```